# Arduino compatible chip wthout need of crystal for serial communication

Tags: arduino, serial-port, microchip

I am asking this well ahead of applying it to get myself a chance to study content of answers.

Basically the question is if there is Arduino compatible chip (I am not interested in boards) which does not need external crystal to keep it in close enough sync to run serial (232) communication. To mine knowledge the atmegas builtin crystals are not very well calibrated. The speed of communication does not need to be high in fact I see no problem for less then 0.3kb per second.

Comment: asking for hardware recommendations is off-topic. your post will be closed soon sorry. this is a programming community btw.

Comment: is there a hardware edition f stack-overflow?

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know its off topic, but  best I have found was RTL8710 Roughly the the atmegas price, enough i/a with extra wifi as bonus. In case somebody is looking for answer